# Display all data in table form with Laravel 10

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I have been stuck with this error about 3 hours either with error message `Undefined variable $certificates` or `Call to a member function isEmpty() on array`or any other errors. Actually, I wanna display certificate data belongs to user that logs in instead all data. But I got frustated, thats why I wanna display all data.

Here's my SaveController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Certificate;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SaveController extends Controller
{
    function store(Request $r)
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $format = $now->format('D j-M-Y g:i:s.u A');
        $user = Auth::user();
        $certificate = new Certificate();
        $certificate->user_id = $user->id;
        $certificate->name = $r->input('name');
        $certificate->sha512 = $r->input('sha512');
        $certificate->time = $format;
        $certificate->save();
        // $certificates = Certificate::where('user_id', $user->id)->orderBy('time')->get();
        $certificates = Certificate::all();
        return redirect('/')->with(compact('certificates'));
    }
}
```

and this is my index.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
    <title>Non-Academic Digital Certificate Validator (SHA-512)</title>
</head>
<body>
    @guest
        <header>
            <h1 id="head1">Non-Academic Digital Certificate Validator (SHA-512)</h1>
            <div class="auth">
                <a href="/login"><button>Login</button></a>
                <a href="/register"><button>Register</button></a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="input">
            <div id="droppable-zone">
                <div id="droppable-zone-wrapper">
                    <div id="droppable-zone-text">Drag & drop your certificate here OR click to browse</div>
                </div>
                <input class="droppable-file" id="input" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf"
                    onchange="hash()">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="output">
            <textarea id="output" placeholder="SHA-512 Checksum" readonly></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="remove">
            <button id="remove" onclick="clearInput()">Remove</button>
        </div>
    @endguest
    @auth
        <header>
            <h1 id="head1">Non-Academic Digital Certificate Validator (SHA-512)</h1>
            <div class="auth">
                <form class="search">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                </form>
                <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <button>Logout</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="input">
            <div id="droppable-zone">
                <div id="droppable-zone-wrapper">
                    <div id="droppable-zone-text">Drag & drop your certificate here OR click to browse</div>
                </div>
                <input class="droppable-file" id="input" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf" onchange="hash()">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="output">
            <textarea id="output" placeholder="SHA-512 Checksum" readonly></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="remove">
            <button id="remove" onclick="clearInput()">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <div class="save">
            <form action="{{ route('save') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="name" id="namefile" readonly>
                <input type="hidden" name="sha512" id="hash" readonly>
                <button id="save" type="submit" disabled>Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>SHA-512</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{-- @if ($certificates->isEmpty())
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">No Data</td>
                    </tr>
                @else --}}
                    @foreach ($certificates as $c)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $c->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c->time }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c->sha512 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                {{-- @endif --}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @endauth
</body>
</html>
```

this is my Routes web.php

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SaveController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'auth']);
Route::post('/save', [SaveController::class, 'store'])->name('save');
Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

I have define all classes on web.php too.

Ive tried modified those 2 file but theres nothing work, only return error message. Could someone help me? thx in advance

Comment: You probably don't want `redirect()->with()` for this. Have the `/` route do the `Certificates::all()` call, not the `store` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with function will set the certificates to session data, so to access certificates you need to check if session has certificates

```
@if (session('certificates'))
    @foreach ($certificates as $c)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $c->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $c->time }}</td>
            <td>{{ $c->sha512 }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">No Data</td>
    </tr>
@endif
```

Check the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Better approach will following the standard

- Rename the SaveController to CertificateController this will be more
  clear
- Use Request Validation to validate your request before inserting to database [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#introduction)
- Change Your route to
  `Route::post('certificate',[CertificateController::class,'store']);`
- within your store method of CertificateController Redirect to base
  route
- change your base route '/' to call a controller method maybe like
  HomeController index function
  `Route::get('/',[HomeController::class,'index']);`

in HomeController index get all certificates and return it the view

```
public function index()
{
    $certificates = Certificate::get();
    // it would be better to paginate over the results and 
    // implement pagination in the html side too
    return view('index', compact('certificates');
}
```

now in view you could access the $certificates as you did in your
code

Comment: Correct, but OP would be much better with an entirely different approach. The `redirect()->with()` will *flash* it to the session; a refresh will lose all the certificate data.

Comment: Yes for sure, even the naming of controllers and routes could be better i will try to edit the answer and explain all of that

Comment: I did use this, but if I log out and log in, the data is disappeared. session is just temporary save on our cookies

Comment: the with function will flash the data to the session, so when you log out the session is cleared and when you login back there is certificates in the sessions as you didn't flash it to the session anywhere

Comment: anyway, i dont need the validation because it inserted well when i press save button. it submitted well. the problem is just the displaying, in the index there's a table when u already logged in. it should be appear "No Data" because the user didn't submit certificate yet, after they submit, it stored on the database with no problems. but when redirected to the main page (i.e '/' or index) still display no data.

Comment: then change your base route '/' to call a controller method and return the certificates there, and after storing the certificates redirect to '/' . use your blade code if you go with approach and all should be working.

Comment: The reason you see is certificates after session redirection. If you want to see the certificates after refreshing the page. You have to query on the main page `$certificates = Certificate::all();`

Comment: thats why i tried to display all certificate data that has been submitted. but i cant get request data and display it to the main page

Comment: Create a HomeController and add a function called index like above in my answer.
change Route::get('/', function(){ return view('index')}); to Route::get('/',[HomeController::class,'index']);

Comment: well, the code is working fine. it displayed. but I wanna ask something, why I have to create new controller to return the index? why i cant do it all once in CertificateController (mine still SaveController anyway)

Comment: You can do it in the CertificateController, but you don't want to do it in the `store()` function. That's for storing a new certificate, not displaying the list.

Comment: yeah i have renamed it, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get data on index page for that you need to change this

return redirect('/')->with(compact('certificates'));

to

return view('index')->with(compact('certificates'));

I hope this will help you. Thanks